# Page refresh instead of Ajax Load without

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

On form submit i want to load a div with an updated list of a mysql table. I'am sending the form variables across to a php and posting them into a mysql table. the same page displays the full table data. I want to load the data into the same div tag as the form. So it appears that the information is being loaded above the form.

My Javascript

```
$("#formSubmit").submit(function(){

    var name = $("input#name").val();
    var comment = $("input#comment").val();
    var filmnumber = $("input#hidden").val();

    var dataString = 'name='+ name + '&comment=' + comment + '&filmnumber=' + filmnumber;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "comment.php",
        data: dataString,
        success: function() {
            $('#2').load('comment.php');
        }
    });
```

My form -

```
<div id="2">                                    
    <p>Add a Comment</p>
    <form id="formSubmit" method="POST">
        <div>
            <input type="hidden" name="hidden" id="hidden" value="2">
            <label for="name">Your Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />

            <label for="body">Comment Body</label>
            <textarea name="comment" id="comment" cols="20" rows="5"></textarea>

            <input type="submit" id="comment" class="button" value="Submit" />
    </form>
    </div>
```

All it is doing is refreshing the page and not loading the information in to div 2 :S

thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to prevent the form from redirecting the page using the `preventDefault` method on the event object:

```
$("#formSubmit").submit(function(e){ // add the event object as an argument to your function
    e.preventDefault(); // right here

    var name = $("input#name").val();
    var comment = $("input#comment").val();
    var filmnumber = $("input#hidden").val();

    var dataString = 'name='+ name + '&comment=' + comment + '&filmnumber=' + filmnumber;

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "comment.php",
      data: dataString,
      success: function() {
       $('#2').load('comment.php');
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i have implemented it however it is still not working, is there anychance you could take a look at this page between lines 115 & lines 153? - view-source:http://ignitethatdesign.com/CheckFilm/test_search_comments.php I don't know whether i have placed the script at the right stage

Comment: You would be better off sticking ALL of your scripts at the bottom of the page right before the closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: that script shouldnt have an issue if it was placed directly under the form div tag though right?

Answer (score 1):

add a return false to the end to stop the form from submitting.  or if you want to be more elegant use the preventDefault();  method.  personally for something as simple as this though i just stick with return false;

```
$("#formSubmit").submit(function(e){ // add the event object as an argument to your function


var name = $("input#name").val();
var comment = $("input#comment").val();
var filmnumber = $("input#hidden").val();

var dataString = 'name='+ name + '&comment=' + comment + '&filmnumber=' + filmnumber;

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "comment.php",
  data: dataString,
  success: function() {
   $('#2').load('comment.php');
  }
});
return false;//right here
```

});

Comment: `return false` will preventDefault, but it will also stop event propagation.

Comment: if you use return false at the end of the code provided, it will work just fine.  however you are right, if there is more to the code than whats provided, this could cause problems.  but if its just stopping a form from submitting, return false will be fine.

Comment: I understand that the code would work fine, but if there are other submit events higher up, they wouldn't be triggered correctly, because you stopped the event from propagating.

Comment: ohhh i just copied yours because it was closer to where i was typing.  Its the same as the top isn't it?