# load form at the same page without refreshing

Tags: php

I have the beneath page and when i need to enter another education background so i enter it in a html base.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mnA7.jpg

As i am newbie in PHP so i need help in this regard.

I wanted to ask that is there a way to make it dynamic i mean when i click on that plus sign then a form form should come the first row without refreshing the page and by clicking on submit button it should save to database and come to the first row.

Like stackoverflow.com comment section.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use [preventdefault](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) on the event object.

Please check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10419079/page-refresh-instead-of-ajax-load-without) for  further clarification..